# 1046 AS3 Compile Time Error

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having major issues with this one error

```
//Obligitory Stop
stop();

//Imports
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import fl.motion.easing.Back;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.accessibility.Accessibility;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


//Variables
var bulletSpeed:uint = 20;
var scoreData:int;
var bullets:Array = new Array();
var killCounter:int;
var baddieCounter:int;
var currentLevel:int = 1;
var baddieDamage:int;
var energyCost:int;
var target:MovieClip;
var baddies:Array = new Array();
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1);
var baddieSpeed:int;
var score:int;
var levelKR:int;
var level1KR:int = 10;
var level2KR:int = 25;
var level3KR:int = 50;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var Baddie:MovieClip
var mySound:Sound = new ShootSFX(); 

//Level Atributes set
if (currentLevel == 1)
{
    baddieSpeed = 2;
    baddieDamage = 20;
    timer.delay = 4000;
    levelKR = level1KR;
    bulletSpeed = 10;
    energyCost = 50;
    var energyTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);
    var healthTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
}

//Event Listeners
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fireGun);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBaddie);
rbDash.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);

//Timers Start
timer.start();
energyTimer.start();
healthTimer.start();

//Initialize score
Score.text = String("Level "+currentLevel+" - begin!");

//load score data
score = scoreData;

//Checks Kill Counter
checkKillCounter();


//Shoot gun on space
function fireGun(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
    {
        bullet.x = rbDash.x;
        bullet.y = rbDash.y + 50;
        addChild(bullet);
        bullets.push(bullet);

    }

}

//Move Objects
function moveObjects(evt:Event):void
{
    moveBullets();
    moveBaddies();
}

//Move bullets
function moveBullets():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < bullets.length; i++)
    {
        var dx = Math.cos(deg2rad(bullets[i].rotation)) * bulletSpeed;
        var dy = Math.sin(deg2rad(bullets[i].rotation)) * bulletSpeed;
        bullets[i].x +=  dx;
        bullets[i].y +=  dy;
        if (bullets[i].x <-bullets[i].width
        || bullets[i].x > stage.stageWidth + bullets[i].width
        || bullets[i].y < -bullets[i].width
        || bullets[i].y > stage.stageHeight + bullets[i].width)
        {
            removeChild(bullets[i]);
            bullets.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

//Spawns Enemy
function addBaddie(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    updateScore(25);
    var baddie:Baddie = new Baddie();
    var side:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
    if (side == 1)
    {
        baddie.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        baddie.y =  -  baddie.height;
    }
    else if (side == 2)
    {
        baddie.x = stage.stageWidth + baddie.width;
        baddie.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    }
    else if (side == 3)
    {
        baddie.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        baddie.y = stage.stageHeight + baddie.height;
    }
    else if (side == 4)
    {
        baddie.x =  -  baddie.width;
        baddie.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    }
    baddie.speed = baddieSpeed;
    addChild(baddie);
    baddies.push(baddie);
    baddieCounter +=  1;
    if (baddieCounter == levelKR)
    {
        timer.stop();
    }
}

//Moves Enemy
function moveBaddies():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < baddies.length; i++)
    {
        var dx = Math.cos(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
        var dy = Math.sin(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
        baddies[i].x +=  dx;
        baddies[i].y +=  dy;
        if (baddies[i].hitTestPoint(rbDash.x,rbDash.y,true))
        {
            removeChild(baddies[i]);
            baddies.splice(i, 1);
            //HealthBar.gotoAndStop(HealthBar.currentFrame + baddieDamage);
            killCounter +=  1;
            checkKillCounter();
            //if (HealthBar.currentFrame == 100)
            {
                gotoAndStop(5);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            checkForHit(baddies[i]);
        }
    }
}


//Hit detection
function checkForHit(baddie:Baddie):void {//Level 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 166 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Baddie.
    for (var i:int = 0; i < bullets.length; i++)
    {
        if (baddie.hitTestPoint(bullets[i].x,bullets[i].y,true))
        {
            removeChild(baddie);
            removeChild(bullets[i]);
            baddies.splice(baddie.indexOf(baddie), 1);
            bullets.splice(bullets[i]);
            updateScore(100);
            killCounter +=  1;
            checkKillCounter();
        }
    }
}

//Updates score
function updateScore(points:int):void
{
    score +=  points;
    Score.text = String("Points: "+score);
}

//stops timers
function timerStop():void
{
    timer.stop();
    energyTimer.stop();
    healthTimer.stop();
}

//Y axis movement
//totaly not a code snippet
function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        rbDash.y -=  5;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        rbDash.y +=  5;
    }
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP :
            {
                upPressed = true;
                break;

            };
        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            {
                downPressed = true;
                break;

        }
    }
};

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP :
            {
                upPressed = false;
                break;

            };
        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            {
                downPressed = false;
                break;

        }

    }
};

//makes the deg2rad work for the bullets/enemy
function deg2rad(degree)
{
    return degree * (Math.PI / 180);//Had issues with "deg2rad" functions
}

//Removes listeners
function removeAllListeners():void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fireGun);
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBaddie);
}

//Checks if level end
function checkKillCounter():void
{
    EnemiesLeft.text = ("Enemies Left: "+String(levelKR - killCounter));
    if (killCounter == levelKR)
    {
        shutdown();
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}

//Stops everything
function shutdown():void
{
    timerStop();
    removeAllListeners();
    removeChild(target);
}
```

I get Level 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 166   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Baddie.

Thanks Guys
Im trying to get this done today so i can move on

Answer (score 1):

Is `Baddie` a class that is in the default package? If not, you need to import it:

```
import packagename.Baddie;
```

If `Baddie` is a library symbol, make sure you've checked 'Export for ActionScript' and that the linkage name is correct. Also make sure that is is exported in frame 1, or at least before or on the frame that your code is on.

Comment: It isnt a package, it is a movie clip

Comment: @wizardmorax I see, so you mean that `Baddie` is a library symbol?

Answer (score 0):

In you Library, right click on Baddie and choose "properties" and check "export for ActionScript". Now you can use Baddie as a class that extends MovieClip.

Sorry, I didn't notice this was already recommended. Basically, your error cannot find a Class named Baddie, hence why you need to specify the custom class through the Library instance.